# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < at Object.parse (native)

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, rest, ionic-framework

I just created an ionic app which has nothing but just a signup page. What i am doing is using php RESTful web service at backend and MySql is the database. But i am getting this error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ". I have no idea how to solve this error. Please guide me to solve this type of error.

My index.html is:

```
<ion-content class="has-header" ng-controller="SignupCtrl">
    <div class="list list-inset">

   <label class="item item-input">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="userdata.username" placeholder="Enter Username">
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
     <input type="text" ng-model="userdata.email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input">
     <input class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="userdata.password" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
   </label>

   <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signup(userdata)">SignUp</button><br>
   <span>{{responseMessage}}</span>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

My controller code is:

```
.controller('SignupCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.signup = function (userdata) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/lastLog.php",
        crossDomain : true,
        data: {
            email: userdata.email,
            password: userdata.password,
            username: userdata.username
        },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });
    /* Successful HTTP post request or not */
    request.success(function(data) {
        if(data == "1"){
         $scope.responseMessage = "Successfully Created Account";
        }
        if(data == "2"){
         $scope.responseMessage = "Create Account failed";
        }
        else if(data == "0") {
         $scope.responseMessage = "Email Already Exist"
        }  
    });
 }
})
```

My php code is:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $email = $postdata->email;
    $password = $postdata->password;
    $username = $postdata->username;

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",'') or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());;
    mysql_select_db('db_lastLog', $con);

    $qry_em = 'select count(*) as cnt from users where email ="' . $email . '"';
    $qry_res = mysql_query($qry_em);
    $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_res);

    if($res['cnt']==0){
    $qry = 'INSERT INTO users (name,pass,email) values ("' . $username . '","' . $password . '","' . $email . '")';
    $qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
        if ($qry_res) {
            echo "1";
        } else {
            echo "2";;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "0";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't you have a row number with your error ?

Comment: It says "at fromJson (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14543:14)"

Comment: php script is executed at server side.

Answer (score 1):

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`usually means there's an error in your JSON response, since the location of the error is in `fromJson (angular.fromJson)` it means it failed to parse the JSON response. If you open the `network` tab in your console and you check the request, the response probably starts with a `<`, once you fix this error/json it should be working fine

Comment: I want to ask a silly question that do i have to create a json file for this?

Comment: No, (not that famillar with php) but you have to use `json_encode()` to return your data I think